# How to localize breadcrumps from English to Russian?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that utilizes the MUI `Breadcrumbs` component to create a breadcrumb trail based on the current URL. The component looks like this:

```
const Breadcrumbsss = () => {

    const location = useLocation()

    let currentLink = ''

    const crumbs = location.pathname.split('/')
        .filter(crumb => crumb !== '')
        .map(crumb => {
            currentLink += `/${crumb}`

            return (
                <div className="crumb" key={crumb}>
                    <Link to={currentLink}>{crumb}</Link>
                </div>
            )
        })


    return (
        <Breadcrumbs className="breadcrumbs"
                     separator="⯈"
                     aria-label="breadcrumb"
                     sx={{fontSize: "12px", background: "#fff", position:"static"}}>

            {crumbs}
        </Breadcrumbs>
    );
};

export default Breadcrumbsss;
```

When I navigate to a URL such as `http://localhost:3000/spravochnik/groupsTable`, the breadcrumb trail appears as shown in this image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IesfK.png)

I would like to know how I can change the breadcrumb trail to be in Russian. Specifically, I want to replace "spravochnik" with "Справочник" and "groupsTable" with "Группы".

Comment: It seems you need to have array mapping for each crumb from english to russian.

Comment: Look at line 12 and 28 for ideas https://snack.expo.dev/@cjmling/b9ed35